# Remove item from Session array?

Tags: php

I have a cart page which uses an array from a session variable to get the current cart data. However if i want to remove a specific item from the cart how do i go with doing that?

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
array(2) {
  ["package"]=>
  string(43) "name"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(2) "10"
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
  ["package"]=>
  string(44) "name"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(2) "21"
}
[2]=>
array(2) {
  ["package"]=>
  string(38) "name"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(4) "1555"
}
```

}

How do i remove a specific item from the array using unset()?

Comment: Which *specific item* you want to remove from the array?

Comment: [Examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) seem pretty clear to me. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @gre_gor I dont want to unset the entire array, just the array that contains the package name for example?